# Android Studio Service wont started

Tags: android, fragment

I try to use an Service in Android Studio. But the Service didn't run.

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("myTag14", "onStartCommand");

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
Log.d("myTag14", "Service will be called now");

Intent playerIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
getContext().startService(playerIntent);

Log.d("myTag14", "Service called");
```

The MediaPlayerService is inside an class extends the Fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

In Logcat I only see this two lines:

```
Service will be called now
Service called
```

I have read much thinks about Services and tried to copy examples and so on. But I don't find the missing part..

Thank you all in advance for any help!

Comment: Forgot to add it to the AndroidManifest file?

Answer (score 0):

As a response to Samuel Robert, I post an complete answer to apply more Source-Code.

Yes of course, I try to add something into the AndroidManifest, but I wasn't sure if I need it:

```
service android:enabled="true" android:name=".PlayerFragment$MediaPlayerService"
```

But the App will crash then with this Message:

```
Unable to instantiate service .PlayerFragment$MediaPlayerService: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<i.PlayerFragment$MediaPlayerService> has no zero argument constructor
```

But if I read the documentation, I dont need an constructor at all.

Thanks!